# How to configure solr for fresh new website in Hybris?

Tags: indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

What are the steps need to be followed in order to configure solr to newly created website in Hybris(v5.7) which will cover entire solr config like category search,text search,facet search,auto suggest,synonyms etc?

Comment: Are you using the accelerator ?

Comment: yes, i am using B2C accelerator

Comment: Well on the B2C accelerator SOLR is configured out of the box

Answer (score 0):

http://javainsimpleway.com/understanding-solr-configuration-in-hybris/

This was really helpful for me. It has it all. I was able to configure solr correctly after reading it! :)
You only have to be aware that embeded mode is not available anymore in hybris and you have to configure it with the standalone. But this is also explained in this 'tutorial' :)